# Finding eigenvalues of a $3 \times 3$ matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, characteristic-polynomial

> An interval in which all the eigenvalues of the matrix $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 35 & 40 & 13 \\ 11 & 13 & 8 \\ 12 & 4 & 71 \end{pmatrix}$$ lie, is

> (a) $[-5,-17]$

> (b) $[-18,88]$

> (c) $[89,100]$

> (d) $[90,117]$

It can be solved by finding characteristic polynomial and then finding it's zeros but that's a quite tedious calculation. Is there any easier way to solve this problem? Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem may also be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

The sum of the eigenvalues is $tr(A)=35+13+71=119$.

You can use this to eliminate three of the answers.

Comment: So option (b) is the only correct option. Right?

Comment: @Anacardium Yes.

Comment: After getting upvoted and accepted you at last got time to answer my question. People here in this site is too much concerned about their reputation. Sorry for my incompetent interference.

Answer (score 1):

As the determinant is $2329$ and is known to be the product of eigenvalues, this rules out options (a),(c) and (d).

Comment: Sorry. This is way more difficult to calculate the determinant for a lazy person like me. I can't accept your answer.

Comment: Funny comment...

Comment: I am always a funny fellow. Thanks for your remark. 